# Unable to pass function as argument to a mixin

Tags: sass, mixins

I'm trying to create a mixin in Sass to use for the :hover actions but I can't make it work.

I declare the mixin:

```
@mixin hover($action, $color, $amount) {
    color: $action($color, $amount);
}
```

My idea is to use [Sass Script Funcions](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#darken-instance_method) to change the color of the link on hover by basically lightening or darkening it. So for example I try:

```
a {
    &:hover {
        @include hover(darken, $footer-text-color, 5%);
    }
}
```

`$footer-text-color` is a variable I have previously defined which is equal to an hex color, such as #84b3c8.

I would expect this to be identical to

```
 a {
    &:hover {
        color: darken($footer-text-color, 5%);
    }
}
```

Instead, what it's compiled in plain CSS is:

```
color: darken #84b3c8, 5%;
```

So obviously the color function is not working but sincerely I can't understand why. I'm sure it's something silly, maybe the mix between variables and string values in the mixin's arguments?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Functions and mixins are not *first-class* in Sass, meaning they cannot be passed as arguments to other functions or mixins.

In Sass 3.3, there is a new function called `call()` which will give you the behavior you're looking for:

```
@mixin hover($action, $color, $amount) {
    color: call($action, $color, $amount);
}
```

Comment: oh that's good to know, I wasn't aware of this limitation! However, I can't see how using `call()` the way you do is respecting the function syntax, which I guess still should be `color: $action($color, $amount);` ?

Comment: `call()` is a magic function that runs a function named whatever the first argument is, and the following arguments are passed to said function.

Comment: pity 3.3 is still a release candidate version, do you know if there is any documentation about `call()` or about what's new in 3.3?

Comment: https://github.com/nex3/sass/blob/master/doc-src/SASS_CHANGELOG.md