# Higher-order mixins in Sass

Tags: sass

It is well-known that Sass supports higher-order functions, but is it possible to have higher-order mixins? Something like this:

```
@mixin foo($color)
    color: $color

@mixin bar($mixin, $background-color)
    background-color: $background-color
    @include $mixin(complement($background-color))

@include bar(foo, white)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to pass function as argument to a mixin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21675199/unable-to-pass-function-as-argument-to-a-mixin)

Comment: This may be of interest:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21882528/unexpected-results-when-using-extend

Comment: @cimmanon Please read the example. I am trying to pass a mixin to a mixin, not a function. I know about `call`.

Comment: Please read the answer?  "Functions and mixins are not first-class in Sass, meaning they cannot be passed as arguments to other functions or mixins."